# Lucene searching and updating issues

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I created a task in scheduled task to update my lucene index. Everything is going well until I searched in my lucene and the task to update the index run at the same time.

My Code in Lucene is to delete the old index and create a new one, I know that it needs the former file in order to search, but when I put `IndexWriter` Property create to `false`, it works, but the index file folder seems to create more **"files/index"** and the index search list contains the two or three of the same indexed **"term"**.

Is their a way to append it and exclude the previous indexed terms in the update? Because I'm having a hard time to understand the Update Method of Lucene.

Comment: Hi, can you see this https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/fileformats.html it might help you a little in understanding lucene index files. and https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html

Sorry I'm not in touch with it right now. But it's how lucene behaves, it creates multiple index files. Lucene.NET and Lucene have mostly same functionality so I feel above links should help you a little

http://blog.asteriosk.gr/2009/03/31/merging-multiple-lucene-indexes/
above code is in java but should be pretty similar for .net

Comment: @Mandy thank you for your help

Comment: Did it help you? I'm glad if  it did. You are most welcome. 

Comment: It's probably "wrong" to delete the index and rewrite. Consider the index in the same way as a SQL database. In order to add an "order", you wouldn't delete the DB and recreate it, right?
Keep a singleton of your IndexWriter and do Update/Delete operations on it. Then use an IndexSearcher (created from the writer) to do your searches